# Python Flask - avoid posting on dynamic table return to render template

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have this python app using flask having this core routes:

```
@app.route('/test_limit', defaults={'page':1})
@app.route('/test_limit/page/<int:page>')
def test_results_limit(page):
    perpage=10
    startat=page*perpage
    results = []
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from pi_fb_limit limit %s, %s;', (startat,perpage))
    table = list(cursor.fetchall())
    return render_template('results_limits.html', table=table)

@app.route('/infringement/FB/<int:id>')
def infringement(id):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('UPDATE p_test_search SET infringement = ''TRUE'' WHERE ID = %s', (id))  
    db.commit()
    return render_template('results_limits.html')
```

In my HTML file "result_limits.html" I have this HTML code iterating MySQL resoult:

```
 </table>
<tbody>
         {% for tab in table %}
            <tr class="zoomin">
               <th> {{tab[0]}} </th>
               <td> {{tab[9]}} </td>
               <td><button type="button" onclick="location.href='/infringement/FB/'+{{tab[0]}};return false;" class="btn btn-danger">Infringement</button></td>
            </tr>   
         {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

All is working fine but my problem is that when the button above dinamically call the route @app.route('/infringement/FB/'), browser is redirected to
result_limits.html.
Instead I'd like to avoid any redirection and remain on the same page each row button is creating post (to update records).

Any suggestion?
Thank you
Regs
SL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript to submit data without reloading the page.

Something like:

```js
function submit_infringement(id) {
  this.removeAttribute('onclick');  // Prevent sumbitting twice.
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('GET', '/infringement/FB/' + id, true);
  x.onload = function() {
    this.textContent = 'Infringement report sent!';
  }
  x.onerror = function(error) {
    (console.error || console.log)(error);
    this.textContent = 'An error occured. Try again.';
    this.onclick = function() { sumbit_infringemet(id); }
  }
  this.textContent = 'Sending infringement report...';
  x.send(null);
}
```

```html
<td>
  <button type="button" onclick="sumbit_infringement({{tab[0]}});" class="btn btn-danger">
    Infringement
  </button>
</td>
```